# How to replace newline character in the middle of string

Tags: php, regex, xml, xslt, xpath

```
 <xsl:value-of 
      select="concat(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚ¿?&gt;&lt;:,&#10;&#13;', 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz-aeiouuaeiou-------'), '.html')" />
```

I am using this XPath to eliminate unwanted characters from a string:

```
<somenode> This is a string
with new
lines
</somenode>
```

But it doesn't replace newlines (neither `&#10;` nor `&#13;`) as expected. The output still shows them as `%0D%0A`.

In PHP, when I apply this RegEx to the exact same string `/[\n\r]/` (via `$somenode->nodeValue`), it does work as expected.

**UPDATE**

This is my XML, which is a little bit different from the example:

```
<temas>
...
<tema>
    <title>La tildación&#13;
diacrítica </title>
    <nav>
        <menu>
            <menu-item>La ortografía acentual: ¿cómo pongo las tildes? </menu-item>
            <menu-item>La tildación&#13;
diacrítica </menu-item>
            <menu-item>El diptongo y el hiato</menu-item>
        </menu>
    </nav>
    <content>
        ...
    </content>
    <pie>
        <prev>La ortografía acentual: ¿cómo pongo las tildes? </prev>
        <next>El diptongo y el hiato</next>
    </pie>
</tema>
</temas>
```

This is generated from a HTML file. The `^M`s in that file are transformed to `&#13;` and newlines. So, my guess is that the `&#13;` are not matched by the xpath. So my question should be "how do I match the string '&#13' with XPath?".

Comment: Newline is `&#10;`. `&#13;` is carriage return.

Comment: Yep, I know, I tried that also. I am going to update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Barmar has suggested, use `&#10;`, the proper newline character - and [try it online here](http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBth).

If that does not work for you, please show a complete, verifiable sample of your XSLT code (a whole stylesheet) and say what version of XSLT and what processor you are using.

**XML Input**

```
<somenode> This is a string
with new
lines
</somenode>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="somenode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of 
      select="concat(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚ¿?&gt;&lt;:,&#10;', 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz-aeiouuaeiou-------'), '.html')" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<somenode>-this-is-a-string-with-new-lines-.html</somenode>
```

---

Another approach would be to *normalize* all string values before replacing characters in it with `translate()`:

```
concat(translate(normalize-space(.), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚ¿?&gt;&lt;: ', 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz-aeiouuaeiou-------'), '.html')"
```

The `normalize-space()` function removes leading and trailing whitespace and replaces all sequences of whitespace in between with a single space character. Then, your solution does not depend on the occurrence of a specific whitespace character.

---

**EDIT**

With your updated input, it works as well - I have slightly adapted the template match (but not the content):

```
<xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of 
      select="concat(translate(normalize-space(.), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚ¿?&gt;&lt;: ', 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz-aeiouuaeiou-------'), '.html')" />
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try it [here](http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBth/1).

Comment: I know this works with the example, but somehow it doesn't work with my xml. I updated my question with it.

Comment: @Federico Also try the `normalize-space()` variant. If that does not help either, give _all_ the information we need: The ultimate input, how you arrive at this HTML, all the code that processes the XML and XSLT, and so on.

Comment: I think that `&#10;` doesn't work. It's a pity that the OP didn't post the question with an example that is easy to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)?

> **Function:** *string*  **normalize-space**(*string?*)
>
> The [**normalize-space**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space. Whitespace characters are the same as those allowed by the [S](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml#NT-S) production in XML. If the argument is omitted, it defaults to the context node converted to a string, in other words the [string-value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of the context node.

Comment: I'm not sure you noticed, but I have already mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: @MathiasMüller: No I didn't. Let's make it more prominent for the moment.